# Configuring django with LDAP

Tags: ldap, python, django

I have configured LDAP successfully with a python application using little more than these statements in `db/model.py`:

```
from gluon.contrib.login_methods.ldap_auth import ldap_auth
auth.settings.login_methods = [ldap_auth(mode='ad', server='ldap.example.com', base_dn='dc=example,dc=com')]
```

I am trying the same with Django, but all the instructions that I have seen online are fairly complicated.

What would be the Django equivalent to my web2py LDAP setup?

Is there a simple way to debug the LDAP connection process to the django server console?

Here is what I have attempted:

```
import ldap
from django_auth_ldap.config import LDAPSearch, GroupOfNamesType

# LDAP Configuration
AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = "ldap://ldap.example.com"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = ""
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = ""
AUTH_LDAP_USER_DN_TEMPLATE = "uid=%(user)s,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com"

# group names:
#AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com",
#         ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(objectClass=groupOfNames)"
#         )
#AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_TYPE = GroupOfNamesType()
#AUTH_LDAP_FIND_GROUP_PERMS = True
#AUTH_LDAP_CACHE_GROUPS = True
#AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_CACHE_TIMEOUT = 300


AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP = {"first_name": "givenName", "last_name": "sn", "email": "mail"}
AUTH_LDAP_PROFILE_ATTR_MAP = {"home_directory": "homeDirectory"}

AUTH_LDAP_USER_FLAGS_BY_GROUP = {
    "is_active": "cn=active,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com",
    "is_staff": "cn=staff,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com",
    "is_superuser": "cn=superuser,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com",
}

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

This is what I am currently seeing when I try to authenticate:

[image]

Comment: Increase log level on the LDAP side, so you know why this error is happening. For OpenLDAP: http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch6/#loglevel

Comment: Looks like you got a typo in that AUTH_LDAP_USER_DN_TEMPLATE line - the letter "s" after the "uid=%(user)" is making it expect EVERY user ID to end with "s".

Comment: That 's' is actually python string formatting operation. https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/typesseq-strings.html

Answer (score 1):

a while ago while debugging a graphite ldap installation

ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 65535)

which I got from the graphite docs (http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config-local-settings.html).

It might tell you more about what is going on in your app.

Comment: Thanks. This is very helpful. It explains how to use the logging that @kamilhack mentioned.

Comment: not exactly, @kamilhack suggests to increase logging on the ldap server side, my suggestion is for the ldap client side ;-), but both are valid ways to look at the problem.